# How to prevent python from auto closing the terminal

Tags: python, terminal, command-line-interface, pyinstaller

I created a CLI with python and built it as a exe with pyinstaller. When I double click the exe the terminal opens and if my code encounters few condition it will display some warning message and do `sys.exit()`. on `sys.exit()` the terminal closes automatically. So I cant even read that warning message. It also happens with `os.system('cls')`. But when I open an empty terminal and then run my exe (/my_app>./my_app.exe) it works fine and `os.system('cls')` works too. It only happens when I double click the exe to run

```py
if some_condition == False:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Have your script ask for input at the end, before exiting. `input("Press Enter to exit")`

Comment: No, I dont want that. Is there any other way to stop closing it automatically?

Comment: No, there isn't. If it opens the terminal automatically, it closes it automatically.

Comment: How should it know when to close it otherwise?

Comment: Ohh ok, then why `os.system('cls')` closes the terminal instead of clearing it?

Comment: It does clear it. Then the script ends and the window is closed automatically.

Comment: Try `os.system('cls'); time.sleep(60)` and it won't close the terminal for another minute

Comment: What is your script supposed to do, during the time that the terminal is not closing, but it's not waiting for input (which you say you don't want)? Just wait for input, don't echo it and do it in a while loop that only exits under the condition you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code to pause before exiting. This will allow you to see any messages before the terminal window closes.

```
# ... your existing code ...

if some_condition == False:
    print("Your warning message here")  # Display your warning message
    input("Press Enter to exit...")     # Wait for user input before exiting
    sys.exit()

# ... rest of your code ...
```